# Why does Paxos ensure that consensus is reached and does not change?

Tags: algorithm, distributed, distributed-system, consensus, paxos

I have been reading about single-decree Paxos (primarily looking at Paxos Made Simple) yet am confused about if a consensus among Acceptors is guaranteed to not change after being reached.

According to [James Aspnes's notes](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/pinewiki/Paxos.html),

> So now we suppose that some value `v` is eventually accepted by a majority `T` with number `n`. Then we can show by induction on proposal number that all proposals issued with higher numbers have the same value (even if they were issued earlier).

However, I am confused since I believe I have a counterexample, shown below. Feel free to jump to step 12 since that is where simple steps can illustrate the problem. I have included steps 1-12 in case it is not possible to reach the state in step 12.

Consider the following behavior. Borrowing notation from [Contradiction in Lamport's Paxos made simple paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880949/contradiction-in-lamports-paxos-made-simple-paper).
That is, `X(n:v, m)`, means Acceptor `X` has largest accepted proposal `n:v`, where `n` is proposal number and `v` is value, and `m` is the largest numbered prepare response to which Acceptor `X` has responded.

Say we have 3 Acceptors A, B, C. Let Px be a proposer, or even multiple proposers, who keeps sending proposals since they don't find out about any consensus being reached.

1. `Px` broadcasts `prepare(1)`
2. `A` and `B` respond with promise, state is `A(:, 1)`, `B(:, 1)`
3. `Px` receives promises from `A` and `B`, confirms majority and broadcasts `accept(1:'foo')`
4. Only `A` receives this accept, state is now `A(1:'foo', 1)`, `B(:, 1)`, `C(:,)`
5. `Py` broadcasts `prepare(2)`
6. `B`, `C` respond with promises, state is now `A(1:'foo', 1)`, `B(:, 2)`, `C(:,2)`
7. `Py` receives promises from `B` and `C`, confirms majority and broadcasts `accept(2:'bar')`
8. Only `B` receives this accept, state is `A(1:'foo', 1)`, `B(2:'bar', 2)`, `C(:,2)`
9. `Pz` broadcasts `prepare(3)`
10. `A` and `C` response with promise, state is `A(1:'foo', 3)`, `B(2:'bar', 2)`, `C(:,3)`
11. `Pz` receives promises from `A` and `C`, confirms majority, notes that `1:'foo'` is the largest numbered accepted value, and broadcasts accept `3:'foo'`
12. Only `C` receives this accept, state is `A(1:'foo', 3)`, `B(2:'bar', 2)`, `C(3:'foo', 3)`
    -- A consensus has been reached! 'foo' is the value decided upon --
13. `Pn` doesn't know about this, broadcasts `prepare(4)`
14. `A` and `B` response with promise, state is `A(1:'foo', 4)`, `B(2:'bar', 4)`, `C(3:'foo', 3)`
15. `Pn` receives promises from `A` and `B`, confirms majority, notes that `2:'bar'` is the largest numbered accepted value, and broadcasts accept `4:'bar'`
16. `A` receives this broadcast, state is `A(4:'bar', 4)`, `B(4:'bar', 4)`, `C(3:'foo', 3)`.
    -- A consensus has been reached! 'bar' is the value decided upon --

To be clear, steps 4, 8, 12, don't necessarily mean that the other nodes "failed", but I think it can just the proposer in question is taking a *really* long time to deliver the messages. Thus this shouldn't be a case where more than N acceptors crash in out of 2N + 1.

The top-voted answer in [Contradiction in Lamport's Paxos made simple paper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29880949/contradiction-in-lamports-paxos-made-simple-paper) suggests that Proposers only sent accept messages to Acceptors who promised them **and** an acceptor accepting a value means updating the maxBal. Both of these are satisfied in the above example, yet it shows how consensus can flip-flop between two different values. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to copy&paste a statement straight from Paxos article in wikipedia: "consensus is achieved when a majority of Acceptors accept the same identifier number (rather than the same value)".

So in your step 12 "state is `A(1:'foo', 3)`, `B(2:'bar', 2)`, `C(3:'foo', 3)` -- A consensus has been reached! 'foo' is the value decided upon" - there is no consensus yet; even if there is a majority in the value.

p.s.
thanks for the questions, this is a nice highlight on the consensus definition in Paxos!